# reference error javascript, trying to create slideshow but not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to create a slide show using javascript but gives me error as VM271 "index:21 Uncaught ReferenceError: changeimage is not defined
    at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (VM271 index:21)
onclick @ VM271 index:21"

my index.html code is

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Slideshow</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-/Y6pD6FV/Vv2HJnA6t+vslU6fwYXjCFtcEpHbNJ0lyAFsXTsjBbfaDjzALeQsN6M" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4" >
                <a href="#" onclick=""><img src="previous.png" class="mx-
auto d-block"></a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <image src="iphone.jpg" id="slideshow">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <a href="#" onclick="changeimage()"><image src="forward.png" class="mx-auto d-block"></a>
                                                <script src="slideshow.js">

            </div>

        </div>
    </div>

</body>
```

my javascript code is

```
    var images=["iphone.jpg","samsung.jpg","sony.jpg"];
var count=0;

function changeimage(){
    document.getElementById("slideshow").src=images[count];
    count=count+1;

if (count>2){
    count=0;
    }
}
console.log(count);
```

Answer (score 0):

1) You can see the syntax errors in the web developer console.
If you check that you should see you have an if with out brackets "()".

if count > 2. Update: (done)

2) Load the slider script before closing the body tag.

```
...
<script src="slideshow.js"></script>
</body>
...
```

3) Add an id to the  tag and link it to the handler with jquery (which you are using):

```
<a id="btnChngImg" href="#"><image src="forward.png" class="mx-auto d-block"></a>
```

4) Wrap your script to run aflter the page has loaded.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var images=["iphone.jpg","samsung.jpg","sony.jpg"];
    var count=0;

    function changeimage(){
       document.getElementById("slideshow").src=images[count];
       count=count+1;

       if (count>2){
          count=0;
      }
      console.log(count);
    };

    $("#btnChngImg").click(function(){
      changeimage(); 
    });

});
```

5) And check in the console if you get any syntax errors or file not loading.

Comment: Yes, your code worked, no error in console  but it doesn't change image,

Comment: Are you sure slideshow.js is loading? The file is in the document root right? Not ina js folder or somewhere else? You should see files not found in the console when loading the page.

Comment: Your codes worked. Gives no error but when i try to console.log(count) after $("#btnchangeforward").click(function() line, it doesn't print anything in console.

Comment: I added the console.log() statement. It goes inside the function changeimage before closing the loop

Comment: It doesn't console anything. GIves empty result

Comment: Try putting a breakpoint in the debugger and see what happens. I don't see any reason for the count not to be logged.

Comment: In fact I have just simulated the function in the console and it prints the count each time the function is called.

Comment: yea you are right but it prints nothing at the moment

Answer (score 0):

A little improvement of [Juan's code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46621128/179669). Modulus will range from 0 (first image in the array), to the last which is `images.length - 1`. `count = 1` is in order not to show the first image twice.

```
var count=1;

function changeimage(){
   $("#slideshow").attr("src", images[count++ % images.length] );
}; 

$("#btnChngImg").click(function(){
  changeimage(); 
});
```